# Is there any way to change a variable's address?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm trying to make a linked list with a set of data and I'm wondering if there's a way to make a variable's address change. Something like:

```
for(int i=array.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    Node *previous_ptr;
    Node *current_ptr = new Node(array[i], previous_ptr);
    previous_ptr=current_ptr;
    delete current_ptr;
}
```

So I want current_ptr's address to change (allocate a different spot of memory) so the linked list gets constructed if that's possible.  And I can't use alloc for it only new and delete.

Comment: "And I can't use alloc for it only new and delete." - so homework then?

Comment: Yea.  I know how to do the homework other ways but I'm curious to see if this way will work.

Comment: Side note: `for(int i = array.size(); i--; )` Same result, much more idiomatic.

Comment: @syam that's a very bizarre way to write a loop! I wouldn't expect that to be readable to most developers. But regardless, it's also different from what user2884773 wrote. Yours will stop when `i == 0`, whereas user2884773's will execute one additional time, won't it?

Comment: @user1118321 _post_-decrement. When `i` is `0`, the expression `i--` will decrement `i` to `-1` but still return `0`.

Comment: @user1118321 Do it on paper and you'll see they are strictly equivalent. The only difference is that mine works even for unsigned types. And concerning readability, it is a well known idiom (used either when you need to go downwards using unsigned indexes, or you don't care about order but care about performance -- mine requires one comparison less per iteration) so anyone not able to read this should learn it. I for one would expect most developers to understand it straight away.

Comment: There's something wrong with the question. A variable essentially *is* its address. Do you want to make a *copy?*

Comment: "I want current_ptr's address to change (allocate a different spot of memory) so the linked list gets constructed if that's possible." But you are already doing it! `new Node(...)` will give you a different address every time you call it.

Comment: @EJP I want the same variable name but a different address, not a copy

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thats what I thought but when I print the address, it doesn't change.  previous_ptr just ends up being the same as current_ptr

Comment: 'The same variable name but a different address' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls of `new` produce different addresses every time you call it, unless you call `delete`, in which case the memory becomes reusable, so operator `new` can return it again.

Your code creates hanging pointers: when you call `delete` on line 3

```
Node *current_ptr = new Node(array[i], previous_ptr);
previous_ptr=current_ptr;
delete current_ptr;
```

the value of `current_ptr` and `previous_ptr` immediately become invalid. At the same time, the pointer returned by `new` becomes eligible for reuse, so you get the same pointer when you call `new` again.

You should not call `delete` on anything that you plan to use again.

In addition, `previous_ptr` declared inside a `for` loop is not useful, because its value is thrown away on each iteration. If you would like to keep that pointer between iterations, declare it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot change a variables address and it doesn't make any sense to me, if you think about what is happening in the background.
If you need a different address for your data, allocate new memory, store your data a 2nd time and delete the old data.